# match field on lookup `from` collection for slice element is not working

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using golang as backend with mongodb ,using mgo collection

My mongodb collections are

```
employee
{
  _id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"qwert",
  "emp_id":111,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
  "qualification":"PHD",
   "employee_status":"working"
}
{
_id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"asdfg",
  "emp_id":121,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
 "qualification":"MBA"
 "employee_status":"working"
}
department{
_id:ObjectId(),
"dept_id":11,
"dept_name":"XYZ",
"description":"decs",
"department_status":"active"
}
```

My Go Code is

```
 type DepartmentInfo struct {
    DepartmentID    int                `json:"dept_id" bson:"dept_id"`
    DepartmentName  string             `json:"dept_name" bson:"dept_name"` 
    Description     string             `json:"description" bson:"description"` 
    EmployeeList    []EmployeeInfo     `json:"employee_list" bson:"employee_list"`
}
 type EmployeeInfo struct {
    EmployeeID    int                `json:"emp_id" bson:"emp_id"`
    EmployeeName  string             `json:"emp_name" bson:"emp_name"` 
    Qualification string             `json:"qualification" bson:"qualification"` 
    Dept_Name     string             `json:"emp_dept" bson:"emp_dept"` 
    Address       string             `json:"address" bson:"address"`
}

collection := session.DB("db").C("department")
pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{
        {"$match": bson.M{ "dept_id": 104, }},
        {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "from":         "employee",
        "localField":   "dept_name",
        "foreignField": "emp_dept",
        "as":           "employee_list",
    }},
      {"$match": bson.M{ "employee_list.qualification": "PHD", }},  
    })
var departmentInfo Department
err = pipeline.One(&departmentInfo)
```

It returns department information with all employee's List without matching their qualification. So how to apply match operator on `slice` returned by `lookup` from collection?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $match for your last stage, you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) as part of a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) stage.

So your pipeline would look like the following:

```
[{
    $match: {
        dept_id: '11'
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'employee',
        localField: 'dept_name',
        foreignField: 'emp_dept',
        as: 'employee_list'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        dept_id: 1,
        dept_name: 1,
        description: 1,
        employeesWithPHD: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$employee_list',
                as: 'employee',
                cond: {
                    $and: [{
                            $eq: [
                                '$$employee.qualification',
                                'PHD'
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $eq: [
                                '$$employee.employee_status',
                                'working'
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: I want to compare multiple parameters in `$eq`. How we can do this?

Comment: You can combine multiple $eq statements with $and. I've updated my answer above to reflect that.